# Url.Action does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I am using ASP.Net Core.

I have a function I am trying to move to a separate class to be called by multiple controllers.

This function woud build a pdf with links inside it.
For the links, I use:

```
string urlMeeting = Url.Action("Detail", "Event", new { id = "meeting-" + MeetingID });
```

It works perfectly fine in my controller but when I move the function from the controller into a separate class in the same project, I keep getting `"The name Url does not exist in the current context"`.

I tried adding `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;` but same error.

What did I miss? Why doesn't it complain in my controller and does in my external class?

Comment: Is the class located in the same workspace? So all references were added as well?

Comment: @KimKulling, yes same project so probably the same workspace. All references are added...

Comment: `Url` is a property on the controller and hence you cant access it from within another class. You may accept `UrlHelper` as parameter to the constructor of your class and initialize your class from your controller and pass `Url` to it.

Comment: @shahkalpesh it sounds good. Do you have some examples?

Comment: Lets say you have your custom class named MyClass. You may have a constructor for e.g. `MyClass(UrlHelper url) { this.url = url; }` . You may now use `url` within instance of MyClass similar to how you could use it within Controller.

Comment: Thank you. I also add to include the following code in my Startup.cs `services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x => { var actionContext = x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
                var factory = x.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
                return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);});` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Because your custom controller does inherit from the controller class.
This means u Have access to the Url property in the base class.
But when u move the code to a seperate class u dont have access to that property.

A solution to this is to parametrize the function that you are calling with the Url.